# split string from file with no spaces

Tags: python, file, variables, file-io, split

I am trying to split the first line of the file into 3 separate values but it gives me an error

> ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 1)

```
#open files
infile = open("milkin.txt","r").readlines()
outfile = open("milkout.txt","w")


#instantiate variables
a,b,c = infile[0].split()
```

milkin.txt

```
abc
def
ghi
```

Comment: Try `a,b,c = infile[0]`

Comment: @0x51ba so what? ``a,b,c = list("abc")`` works fine, as does ``a,b,c = "abc"``

Comment: The line is exactly 3 characters? @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ is close but hasn't accounted for the newline. `a,b,c = infile[0][:3]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, `split()` uses whitespace by default if no argument is specified.

```
>>> 'abc'.split()
['abc']
```

Fortunately, to unpack a string into multiple values you do not need to `split()` the string.  Since a string is itself iterable, you can unpack multiple values so long as you can ensure the length of the string matches the number of declaring variables.

```
>>> a, b, c = 'abc'
>>> a
'a'
>>> b
'b'
>>> c
'c'
```

Also, the `readlines()` method of a file object returns a list of strings that contain a trailing newline character, so what you might think is just the string `'abc'` at `infile[0]` is really `'abc\n'`.

This should work:

```
a, b, c = infile[0].strip()
```